# Postgres logs fatal error due to parallel worker

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to debug a FATAL error on my postgres instance, but from the logs I have not could reached any conclusion and don't know much about the specifics of this error:

`user=, db=, app=, client=, FATAL:  terminating background worker "parallel worker" due to administrator command`

What does this error means ? And where could I look further to investigate why this happens ?

Thanks.

Comment: As always when you have trouble with a database: look into the log file.

Comment: It would be very odd for that error to occur in isolation in the log file.  Look at the other messages around it for the likely source.

Answer (score 0):

These FATAL errors are caused by "parallel workers" being aborted because they're no longer needed.

PostgreSQL can devise query plans that can leverage multiple CPUs in order to answer queries faster. This feature is known as a parallel query. So during parallel query execution, it will plan for the background worker processes needed and then terminate the process once the query is completed. below is the sample parallel query execution plan devised by PostgreSQL.

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE filler LIKE '%x%';
                                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------​------------------
     Gather  (cost=1000.00..217018.43 rows=1 width=97)
       Workers Planned: 2
       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pgbench_accounts  (cost=0.00..216018.33 rows=1 width=97)
             Filter: (filler ~~ '%x%'::text)
    (4 rows)
```

So in the above query planning, PostgreSQL planned to use 2 background worker processes and once the query is completed it will terminate those processes.

Reference:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/OF29BEBFE9.F4E15BD2-ONC12585F4.0042F4DE-C12585F4.0043824E%40apollotyres.com
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/how-parallel-query-works.html
3. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html
4. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html

Comment: This appears to be causing stream exceptions for clients running queries, which correlate to these errors.